# Search arrays then echo with conditionals?

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to do somthing like this:

```
  $random = array("apple","celery","banana");

  $define_fruits = array("apple","banana","pears","mango");
  $define_vegetables = array("celery","lettuce","carrots","cucumber");

  if($random contains only fruits){
    echo fruits;
  }elseif($random contains only vegetables){
    echo vegetables;
  }elseif($random contains both fruits and vegetables){
    echo both;
  }
```

SOLVED:

```
$in_fruits = sizeof(array_intersect($random,$define_fruits));
$in_vegetables = sizeof(array_intersect($random,$define_vegetables));

      if($in_fruits >= 1 && $in_vegetables >= 1){
          echo "in_fruits and in_vegetables "; 
        }elseif($in_fruits === 0 && $in_vegetables >= 1){
          echo "in_fruits "; 
        }elseif($in_fruits >= 1 && $in_vegetables === 0){
          echo "in_fruits"; 
        }
```

Progression:

```
$in_fruits = count(array_intersect($random,$define_fruits));
$in_vegetables = count(array_intersect($random,$define_vegetables));

if( $in_fruits ){
  if( $in_vegetables )
    echo "both";
  else
    echo "fruits";
}elseif( $in_vegetables ){
  echo "veggies";
}else{
  echo "neither ";
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could probably done more efficiently, but this is a simple way:

```
$random = array("apple","celery","banana");

$define_fruits = array("apple","banana","pears","mango");
$define_vegetables = array("celery","lettuce","carrots","cucumber");

if( count(array_intersect($define_fruits,$random)) ){
  if( count(array_intersect($define_vegetables,$random)) )
    echo "both";
  else
    echo "fruit";
} elseif( count(array_intersect($define_vegetables,$random)) ){
  echo "vegetables";
} else {
  echo "neither";
}
```

Comment: How is this more efficient? It is using array_intersect 3 times. My solve is using it twice.

Comment: I used your structure with the cached vars. Thanks

Comment: If you follow the logic, array_intersect is always called twice, never 3 times. Also my code only has 2 comparisons. Your progression looks good. The only other tweak is there might be a better way to check other then count(), the PHP docs weren't clear, but you can probably just do a check for NULL, instead of having count iterate through the array if one is returned.

Answer (score 6):

You probably want to look at array_intersect:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php

Answer (score -1):

The simplest solution would be:

```
if ( in_array($define_fruits, $random) && ! in_array($define_vegetables, $random) ) {
   // Only fruits
}elseif ( ! in_array($define_fruits, $random) && in_array($define_vegetables, $random) ) {
   // Only Vegetables
}elseif ( in_array($define_fruits, $random) && in_array($define_vegetables, $random) ) {
   // Both fruits and vegetables
}
```

Comment: When you use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php#example-4177) with an array as the needle it will look within the array for an array that is identical.